# java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range

Tags: java, sql

Having the stated problem even after searching around and changing the values and parameters around..
here's my snipped code

```
public int FeePayment(int TempSID, String Surname, String Name, int Amount, int PayType, String PaidFor, Date date, String Remarks)
{
try
    {
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(db_url,db_user,db_pass);
    PreparedStatement SQLStatement = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO receipt (`SID`, `Surname`, `Name`, `Amount`, `PayType`, `PaidFor`, `Date`, Remarks`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

    SQLStatement.setInt(1,TempSID);
    SQLStatement.setString(2,Surname);
    SQLStatement.setString(3,Name);
    SQLStatement.setInt(4,Amount);
    SQLStatement.setInt(5,PayType);
    SQLStatement.setString(6,PaidFor);
    SQLStatement.setDate(7,new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()));
    SQLStatement.setString(8,Remarks);


    SQLStatement.executeUpdate();
    con.close();
    SQLStatement.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException exc)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(DBConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, exc);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there a typo around your post here? (Remarks has no open quote around it).

Comment: You have a typo in your SQL sentence, instead of 'Remarks' you have Remarks' (without the opening quote) do you also have it in your original code? Also, you are using (`) instead of (')

Comment: @ElliottFrisch thats the error. to say it is a typo, i dont think he will type to post here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your query; Remarks has a closing quote, but no open quote.

Comment: That's really sharp eye :D